# Python facepy apostrophe issue

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, apostrophe, facepy

I take some string from Postgresql database by python code and trying to send it to Facebook by API.

```
cur.execute("SELECT  text_column FROM table")
.....
print graph.post(path = str(row["FB_acnt_id"])+'/notifications', template = str(row["_text"]), access_token = fb_token_app, href = str(row["_href_text"]))
```

Everything is working fine, except text with apostrophe.
For example:
Phrase - It's
is shown like - It\047s

How to resolve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the actual line that you execute. The [readme](https://facepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/graph-api.html) does not mention a `template` parameter for post.

Comment: It's a part of:
data – Graph API parameters such as ‘message’ or ‘source’.

Comment: Please post your actual line of code.

Comment: print graph.post(path = str(row["FB_acnt_id"])+'/notifications',  template = str(row["_text"]), access_token = fb_token_app, href = str(row["_href_text"]))